# Excel VBA script copying entire worksheet instead of range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with various sections that need to be saved as individual csvfiles. For example B3:J57 will be one csv file, L3:T57 will be another, and so on. To do this I found a script that works very well, except all of a sudden it is now copying all 1 million+ empty rows into the csv file. Everything below row 57 is empty yet the csvfiles are created with lines and lines of ten commas (the number of columns in each range) at the end. I assuming I have triggered something so it is seeing data in rows 57 and beyond - although I don't know what. Maybe there is something I can do in my script. I am not an expert by any means so any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Leaf Switches")

With wsh.Range("B3:J57")
.AutoFilter 1, "<>" 'Filter to get only non-blank cells
'assuming there is no blank cell within a filled row:
wsh.Range(wsh.Cells(3, 2), wsh.Cells(57, 10).End(xlDown)).Copy 'copy non-blank cells
'.AutoFilter should not cancel autofilter as it clears cutcopy mode
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'avoid from "save prompt window"
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\csv\ushilas222.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
wsh.Range("B3:J57").AutoFilter 'clear the filter
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'set to default
```

Comment: Since everything below row 57 is empty, the `.End(xlDown))` returns the last row in column J, and you have all those empty lines in the csv. Look into copying the visible cells after you've filtered using [`Range.SpecialCells`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel)

Comment: Thanks BigBen. I ended up using xlUp and specified the range end at 58 and that seems to give me what I need.

Comment: Yes that'd work as well...